# Trying to get pid from a script running as su -c

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, init.d

I am trying to get [these scripts](https://orrsella.com/2014/11/06/initd-and-start-scripts-for-scala-java-server-apps/) to work in an environment where the java application needs to run as user `foobar` no matter if it is started as `root` or `foobar`.

So these are my modifications to the `init` script, which is symlinked from `init.d`:

```
RUN_USER=foobar
USER_NAME=$(id --user --name)
START_SCRIPT=/opt/app/scripts/start

ARGS=""

start() {
    if [ "$USER_NAME" != "$RUN_USER" ]; then
        PID=$(su $RUN_USER -c $START_SCRIPT $ARGS > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!)
    else
        PID=`$START_SCRIPT $ARGS > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
    fi
}
```

And my `/opt/app/scripts/start` script looks like this:

```
exec java -jar /opt/app/app.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!
```

To make the `init` script work the `PID` variable needs to be set properly, but it is being set to the `PID` of the `su` command. There are multiple questions about making that work, but none of the solutions work for me. I understand that the `> /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!` part of my `su` command doesn't work, but it doesn't work when I change it to `> /tmp/foobar` either (no file gets written) and I don't know how to make it work. The `su` command on its own (`su foobar -c /opt/app/scripts/start`) will output the `PID` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You echoed java pid inside ***/opt/app/scripts/start*** script which is true but again echoed pid of ***su*** command inside the init script. I think you should change init script like this:

```
start() {
if [ "$USER_NAME" != "$RUN_USER" ]; then
    PID=$(su $RUN_USER -c "$START_SCRIPT $ARGS")
else
    PID=`$START_SCRIPT $ARGS`
fi
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing but I forgot to update here.